# How to Foreach the marker in Maps, using retrofit2?

Tags: java, android

I have problem in foreach the marker in Maps Android Google Maps API

I've tried using ArrayList foreach, but the marker on the map still doesn't appear, maybe I have an error in my syntax

```
private void Koordinat() {

        Call<List<LatlongModel>> sektorCall = latlongInterface.GetLatlong();
        sektorCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<LatlongModel>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<LatlongModel>> call, Response<List<LatlongModel>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                    listLatlong = response.body();
                    ArrayList<Double> itemLatlong = new ArrayList<Double>();
                    for (int x = 0; x < response.body().size(); x++) {

                        Double latitude = response.body().get(x).getLatitude();
                        Double longitude = response.body().get(x).getLongitude();

                        itemLatlong.add(latitude);
                        itemLatlong.add(longitude);

                        latLongA = new LatLng(longitude, latitude);


                    }

                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLongA)
                            .title("Citarum")
                            .snippet("Titik A")
                            .rotation((float) 3.5)
                            .icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_action_hijau)));


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "response message"+ response.body().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<LatlongModel>> call, Throwable t) {

                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

    }
```

Markers come from the following JSON response:

{"id": 1, "titk": "Titik A1", "lat": -6.9155332, "long": 107.4724021, "idSector": 1}

{"id": "1," titk":"Titik A2"," lat ": -6.9153333," long ": 107.4725922," idSector ": 1}

My expectations are for markers to appear on maps from the lat and long JSON responses above

Answer (score 0):

Assuming nMap is already initialized, I believe your mMap.addMarker should be inside the loop instead of being outside. Can you check that?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the markers to your map should be done inside the for loop not outside. Your code should look something like below.

Note: I changed the for loop into a foreach loop to make things look cleaner.

```
private void Koordinat() {

        Call<List<LatlongModel>> sektorCall = latlongInterface.GetLatlong();
        sektorCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<LatlongModel>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<LatlongModel>> call, Response<List<LatlongModel>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                    listLatlong = response.body();
                    for (LatlongModel latLongModel : response.body()) {

                        LatLng latLongA = new LatLng(latLongModel.getLatitude(), latLongModel.getLongitude());

                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLongA)
                            .title("Citarum")
                            .snippet("Titik A")
                            .rotation((float) 3.5)
                            .icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_action_hijau)));

                    }




                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "response message"+ response.body().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<LatlongModel>> call, Throwable t) {

                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

    }
```